# using dojox.form.PasswordValidation in Programatic Way

Tags: dojo

Im building a registration form and planning to use dojox.form.PasswordValidation to verify if the inputted passwords are the same. Is there a way to use dojox.form.PasswordValidation programatically? If i do this:

```
<div id="sample">
    <input type="password" pwType="new" />
    <input type="password" pwType="verify" />
</div>

<script>
    var a = new dojox.form.PasswordValidation({}, "sample");
</script>
```

The above code works as expected, but I want to strip-off those "pwType" tags and create a pure HTML tags only. If I do that, where should I put "pwType"?

P.S. I'm using Dojo 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like this widget is not really up-to-date with the recent changes where dojo tries to move all the invalid html attributes into the valid data-* attributes. When looking at the `postCreate` method of that widget it has this code in the middle of it:

```
dojo.forEach(["old","new","verify"], function(i){
    widgets.push(dojo.query("input[pwType=" + i + "]", 
                            this.containerNode)[0]);
}, this);
```

And just afterwards it makes sure that it found the necessary inputs, otherwise it will throw an error.

So if you want to use something other than the `pwType` attributes, then you will probably have to overwrite the postCreate method of this widget to query something else, for example:

```
dojo.query("input[data-dojo-password-type=" + i + "]")
```

and then you can specify the values in `data-dojo-password-type` instead of `pwType` like this:

```
<div id="sample">
    <input type="password" data-dojo-password-type="new" />
    <input type="password" data-dojo-password-type="verify" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about something like :

```
var theDiv = dojo.create("div", {id: "sample"}),
    theNewPass = dojo.create("input", {type: "password", pwType: "new"}, theDiv, "last"),
    theVerifPass = dojo.create("input", {type: "password", pwType: "verify"}, theDiv, "last"),
    a = new dojox.form.PasswordValidation({}, "sample")
;
```